# Is it possible to get file from File upload dialog input by URL?

Tags: html, excel, selenium

I want to upload a file using selenium to open file dialog and input URL which is grabbed from html**([timeZone.xlsx](https://connect.wdc.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/467244-5-476725/timeZone.xlsx) href="https://connect.wdc.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/467244-5-476725/timeZone.xlsx">timeZone.xlsx)** .Then i click 'Open'. But don't know why the uploaded file name changes to **"timeZone[1].xlsx"** and size is bigger than the original one directly downloaded from website .And then when i click to save the changes , the file extension changes from **.xlsx** to **.xlsx.zip** .The following step is to unzip the file to **.xlsx** to open . then Excel gives me error that says **"Excel cannot open the file 'filename. xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."** . i change the file extension to ".xls" but still don't work .

Is it possible to get file from File upload dialog input by URL ? and can anyone explain  why the file name/size/extension is changed and cannot open the file ? I am confused .Your response is appreciated .

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pyautogui
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(os.path.abspath(ChromeDriverManager().install()))    
url='https://xxxx'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

# **( omitted some codes irrelevant to this topic)**
# **below is starting to attach file with URL**

attach= WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="attachmentButton"]'))
attach.click()
time.sleep(3)

# **filepath is grabbed from html code .and i could get the downloaded file and open it by inputting url to broswer address bar using my network.**

filepath= 'https://connect.wdc.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/467244-5-476725/timeZone.xlsx'
pyautogui.write(filepath,interval=0.25)
pyautogui.press('return')

# **then i get the "timeZone[1].xlsx" which is not same as the original one**
```

[enter URL]  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Dn4.png
[2] :The left attachment is original one ,the other one is attached by link.[result]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi710.png

Comment: I'm having trouble following your process here... to answer the main question, though you need a local path for a file upload.  (a site could implement a way to retrieve a file using a URL, but it wouldn't use <input type='file' for that...)  When you save "click to save the changes" I'm not sure it's clear what exactly you are clicking on.  Can you edit to include a specific procedure that produces the "zip"?

Comment: Thank your for you comment . Actually i don't click the 'Open' but  pyautogui did it by pyautogui.press('return')  .It returns the  the file of "timeZone[1].xlsx" . When i manually input the URL and click 'Open'. it still gives me the "timeZone[1].xlsx" . I appended my some codes and pls see that .And what else should i attach for you to better follow my process ?

Comment: what returns the file of "timeZone..."?  What do you mean by "input the URL"?  Are you talking about a local file path there?

Comment: I think the network  returns me the file ,because i can download the file with the URL from address bar .Is my thinking right ?  i am not talking local file path , i am talking the network link(https://....),input the URL means i copy the original file link address and paste it into file name of  file upload dialog .Please see the screenshot below
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3Dn4.png

Comment: not sure exactly what "attach" means in this context... but I suppose it's possible it's getting the entire web request including the request headers.  (these would tell the browser you are downloading a file...and pass mime-type?)  that would certainly corrupt the file.